# prevent window from resizing when loading image through @url.HttpRouteUrl

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

Tools being used:
 Knockout 3.1
 MVC 5

I have a list of documents to view.  My image placeholder is like this:

```
<img src="" data-bind="attr: { src: '@Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", New With {.controller = "document"})?documentID=' + DocumentID(), title: FileName}" />
```

I cache the image with my controller, so only on the first load do I have an issue.

But basically, when the image is loaded, the page doesn't know what size the image will be and shrinks down, then when the image is loaded it expands to its regular size.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, add a containing div around the image. Give it a min-height and min-width that doesn't break your layout. This way, while the image is loading, your end users don't see a broken layout, or a "stutter" as your image is bound as the source for the element.